# Nivo Slider forcing background colour in Chrome/Firefox - IE works fine

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, nivo-slider

I've exhausted a fair amount of time investigating this issue and found nothing that has helped, so I'm posting the question here in hope someone may be able to assist.

I've had this issue for a while now but finally found some time to try and resolve the issue. I created our SharePoint based company intranet a few years ago now which was designed for IE as its our corporate browser. Over the past few months there has been an increase in other browsers for various processes, Chrome in particular.

The Nivo Slider on our main portal within IE (9 & 11) works as expected. Images are displayed and rotated as designed.

The issue I have is within Chrome and Firefox the slider does not display the images at all.

EDIT: this section within the CSS `#slider {position:relative; background:#202834;}` is forcing the background colour over the image. I've tried to comment out the bg colour from slider css which has not resolved the issue, it displays a white background instead. /EDIT

The images still rotate within the slider, it's just that the image itself does not appear, example below:

[image: Example]

I've played around with a few options within the CSS and changed the `window.load` to `document.ready` but to no avail. I definitely know it's one of these settings within the CSS, but having a hard time finding out which one is the culprit.

I've attached a copy of the script below which is pretty much untouched from the source code found online:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function() {

 $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    slices: 15, // For slice animations
    boxCols: 8, // For box animations
    boxRows: 4, // For box animations
    animSpeed: 300, // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime: 6000, // How long each slide will show
    startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
    directionNav: false, // Next & Prev navigation
    directionNavHide: false, // Only show on hover
    controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
    controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
    controlNavThumbsFromRel: false, // Use image rel for thumbs
    controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', // Replace this with...
    controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', // ...this in thumb Image src
    keyboardNav: true, // Use left & right arrows
    pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
    manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
    captionOpacity: 0.0, // Universal caption opacity
    prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
    nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
    beforeChange: function() { }, // Triggers before a slide transition
    afterChange: function() { }, // Triggers after a slide transition
    slideshowEnd: function() { }, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
    lastSlide: function() { }, // Triggers when last slide is shown
    afterLoad: function() { } // Triggers when slider has loaded
   });
});
```

```
/* Home Slider */
#slideshow {height:303px; /*background: url('../../../Images/ss_back.png') no-repeat center; margin: 0 0 10px 0;*/}
#slider {position:relative; background:#202834; }
#slider a {border:0; display:block; }
#slider img {position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display:none;}
.nivoSlider {position:relative; top:15px; left:16px; width:100%;}
.nivoSlider img {position: absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:0; padding:0; margin:0; z-index:60; display:none;}
.nivo-slice {display:block;position:absolute;z-index:50;height:100%;}
.nivo-caption {position:absolute; left:0; bottom:-55px; color:#666; font-size:14pt; width:100%; z-index:89;}
.nivo-caption p {padding:0;margin:0;}
.nivo-prevNav {left:5px;}
.nivo-nextNav {right:5px;}
.nivo-controlNav {position:absolute; right:30px; bottom:-55px;}
.nivo-controlNav a {display:block; width:31px; height:23px; background:url('../../../Images/bullets.png') no-repeat; text-indent:-9999px; border:0; float:left; position:relative; z-index:99; cursor:pointer;}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {background-position: -31px 0; font-weight:bold;}
.nivo-directionNav a {display:block; width:50px; height:50px; text-indent:-9999px; border:0; position:absolute; top:45%; z-index:99; cursor:pointer;}
a.nivo-nextNav {background: url('../../../Images/next.png'); right:40px;}
a.nivo-prevNav {background: url('../../../Images/prev.png'); left:10px;}
```

I ran firebug with Firefox and have displayed the findings below. It didn't generate any console errors, but it did highlight certain areas within the NivoSlider div:

[image: NivoSlider div]

One last thing I did notice is that when in IE developer tools, the document mode was set to IE8 standards which was fine. If I changed the document mode to IE9 then it would replicate the same issue within IE.

Is there anyone who could identify from the information supplied why this may be occurring for Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Do `Inspect Element`in Google Chrome and make sure is there any background-color applied in that image.... Or else better post an fiddle

Comment: Hi, the background image colour is coming from the css, this line more importantly, #slider {position:relative; background:#202834; }. As noted, within IE the image is displayed fine in the slider but in Chrome and Firefox this CSS displays the background image. I have tried to comment out that background colour but all it does is show a white background now.

Comment: Hi again, I wish it was that easy to post it via jsfiddle. It's a SharePoint based page and trying to post the HTML via fiddle with all of the associated content types and master pages references wont be much of a help. Isn't there anything within that css that stands out as to why its forcing the background colour over the image link in the slider?